# Total by day needed

Tags: sql

How can I add one thing here, total by day. 
how many invoices were for this type fb by day
which is ididat (yyyymmdd).

```
SELECT DISTINCT idinvn, COUNT(DISTINCT idinvn)     
   FROM CA1665AFCV.SROISDPL T01 WHERE IDIDAT >=        
   20160101 AND IDORDT = 'FB'                          
group by idinvn
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your date field in the select and group by clause. You also don´t need the distinct.

```
     SELECT IDIDAT, COUNT(*)     
       FROM CA1665AFCV.SROISDPL T01 
       WHERE IDIDAT >= '20160101' 
       AND IDORDT = 'FB'                          
    GROUP BY IDIDAT
```

Comment: check this as wellSELECT  IDIDAT, COUNT(DISTINCT idinvn)                 
 FROM CA1665AFCV.SROISDPL T01                          
 WHERE IDIDAT >= 20160101 AND IDORDT = 'FB'            
 GROUP BY rollup(IDIDAT)

Answer (score 0):

If you use group by idinvn you don't need `distinct` and `distinct idinvn`

```
 SELECT idinvn, COUNT(*)     
 FROM CA1665AFCV.SROISDPL T01 WHERE IDIDAT >=        
 str_to_date('20160101', '%Y%m%d') AND IDORDT = 'FB'                          
 group by idinvn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a total count of invoices:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT idivn), substr(ididat, 7, 2) as DAY
FROM CA1665AFCV.SROISDPL
WHERE IDIAT >= 20160101 
  AND IDORDT = 'FB'
GROUP BY substr(ididat, 7, 2)
```

If you need to count by invoice names as well:

```
SELECT count(1), idivn, substr(ididat, 7, 2) as DAY
FROM CA1665AFCV.SROISDPL
WHERE IDIAT >= 20160101 
  AND IDORDT = 'FB'
GROUP BY idivn, substr(ididat, 7, 2)
```